# ROS Answers SE migration: GET 501 error

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,
opening my browser after launching rosecore I get the following:
" Error code 501.
Message: Unsupported method ('GET').
Error code explanation: 501 = Server does not support this operation. "
Everything has been setup following the various tutorials but I was not able to solve the problem.
I'm using Groovy.
I will appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks in advance.
Arnaldo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224613/get-501-error/) by [arnaldo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25671/arnaldo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot connect to the roscore via a web browser.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2016-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are you trying to achieve? For a web interface, you may check [robot web tools](http://robotwebtools.org/).

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-01-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1